# How to bind nested repeater using imagebutton in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I was using a simple html img with jQuery to show the nested table and binding the repeater on itemdatabound. Problem is, this was very expensive by getting all sub items from items in the list at the same time. So I decided it's better when i click the collapse image to show the nested table I should bind the repeater in there.

For this I use imagebutton and command argument to get the ID and use update panel to stop postback from button, but the repeater won't update?

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptInventarioLocalizacoes_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="tblInventarioLocalizacoes" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable text-center">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Nª</th>
                    <th>Localização</th>
                    <th>Etq. Por Inventariar</th>
                    <th>Etq. Inventariadas</th>
                    <th>Precisão</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCollapse" runat="server" Style="cursor: pointer" ImageUrl="../../Images/Collapse/plus.png" Width="20" CommandName="BindEtiquetas" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Localizacao") %>' />

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlInventarioEtiquetas" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ibtnCollapse" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptLocalizacoesEtiquetas" runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table id="tblLocalizacoesEtiquetas" class="nestedtable table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
                                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th>Etiqueta</th>
                                                <th>Validar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRowIndex" runat="server" Text='<%# (((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1) %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblEtiqueta" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Etiqueta") %>' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEtiqueta" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddEtiqueta" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Adicionar Etiqueta" BackColor="#020023" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnInventariar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Inventariar Etiquetas" BackColor="#020023" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRowIndex" runat="server" Text='<%# (((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1) %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lblIdlocalizacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdInventarioLocalizacao") %>' Style="display: none" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLocalizacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Localizacao") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEtiquetasPorInventariar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EtiquetasPorInventariar") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEtiquetasInventariadas" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EtiquetasInventariadas") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPrecisao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Precisao") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `very expensive by getting all sub items`. Keep in mind that this is still happening on a Partial PostBack. All the code is executed as if it were a normal page load. The only difference is that only the content in the UpdatePanel is refreshed. But if you expect to save overhead you are mistaken. Maybe an Ajax solution.

Comment: So do you advice to do this only using ajax? I know it's very expensive because it was taking a few seconds to load

Comment: Depends a bit of the requirements. But if it takes a few seconds then it may be worth using ajax.

Comment: I see, I was trying to avoid ajax cause of all the extra work i have to do setting up a controller. thanks tho

Comment: Maybe you can speed up the DB queries with correct indexes. And if the site is only for employees oid the load times can perhaps be a bit longer.

Comment: I have optimized the queries enough. The data comes from an open query. Not much I can do about it when grabbing over thousands rows.